# Java, HttpURLConnection not reading polish letters

Tags: java, url, utf-8, httpurlconnection

I want to get content from website where are used polish letter (eg. ś, ć, ę etc) by opening connection using `HttpURLConnection`. I set `InputStreamReader` to `UTF-8`, but that didn't help.

This is my class responsibled for connection:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
public class MyConnection {

URL url;
HttpURLConnection conn;

public MyConnection()
{
}
public void setConnection(URL url)
{
    this.url = url;
}
public void connect() throws IOException {
    conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
}

public String getContent() throws IOException
{
    String data = "";
    String tmp;
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn
            .getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
    while ((tmp = rd.readLine()) != null) {
        data += tmp + "\n";
    }
    rd.close();
    return data;
}
}
```

On the website it's like that:

```
270 Słabowski
270 Skubiszyński
270 Orzyłowski
270 Mołdrzyk
270 Łagodzki
270 Lęcznar
```

but my applications reads it like that:

```
Skubiszy�ski
Orzy�owski
Mo�drzyk
�agodzki
L�cznar
```

`�` is square(but it's not displayed here)

`conn.getContentEncoding()` returns null

In file it looks same like in console

Could you tell me how can i change my code that it will work properly?

Comment: If you call `conn.getContentEncoding()` what is the return value?

Comment: _but my applications reads it like that_ Are you simply printing `data`?

Comment: Are you displaying the strings to the console in Windows? Try redirecting to a file and open in another editor.

Comment: `conn.getContentEncoding()` returns `null`.
yes, i'm simply printing `data` in console. I will try to save it to file

@EDIT in file it looks same like in console

Comment: do you know that the data you are consuming is encoded in UTF-8?  also, are you specifying the charset when saving to the file (and opening it in and editor which can handle the charset)?

Comment: That was encoded in `iso-8859-2`. I didn't check that. Thank you for asking about type of encoding in website. You solved my problem

Comment: @SylwekDerkacz I'm sorry, I asked you for the wrong header, `Content-Type` is what holds (optionally) the charset encoding, not Content-Encoding. Glad you solved your problem.